# C# Command Pattern confusion

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have, unknowingly, been using the command pattern where the client & the invoker are the same and they call the commands directly.  After looking at the definition on [DoFactory](http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern), I am a bit confused.

There are the individual commands.  That hasn't changed from my naive understanding.  I guess the invoker simply calls out all the commands.  But what is the purpose of the receiver?  That I don't get.

If possible, can someone give me an example with multiple commands and how to go about implementing?

Comment: What's exactly unclear to you? The individual command handlers or... ?

Comment: I get the individual commands.  They are the individual task.  I am not sure how the 'Receiver' fit into the picture.

Comment: By my earlier comment I meant that you can't get how command handlers (receivers in your wording) work? Or are you referring events raised by command handlers??

Comment: yes, that is exactly what my confusion is.

Answer (score 1):

The basic intend of [Command](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command) pattern is decoupling the basic(most important) operation of some classes(concrete Command classes) from their real consumer(CommandHandler).

So we are using a work around based on polymorphism. We define an abstract **Command** class which has a method called `void excecute(){}`, so it doesn't get rigid with any method parameter or return type. So the concrete Command classes can implement their class specific implementation inside that method, and the CommandHandler can freely calls out `someCommandObject.execute();` without need to know that exactly that concrete class is (being an instance of Command class is enough). So the calls and implementations are pretty much decoupled. You can easily introduce another concrete Command class in future which implements `void execute(){}`, still the CommandHandler can manage to call that out with `someCommandObject.execute();`. That's the beauty of Command pattern.

It is exact same thing we are having in `Thread.run()` in Java threads and `Task.Run()` in C# threads.

Though you can use a **Receiver** as per your convenience it is a little bit out of the big picture of Command pattern. In your calculator example, it makes sense to have a **Receiver** since all the concrete Command classes can refer that to execute their main operation(`execute()`).

You can see some examples from [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command/java/1) and [there](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/command.html), where a Receiver hasn't been used. It is more than perfect to use a Receiver where it makes sense. But don't get confused of that with the real deal of Command pattern. :))

Comment: Good job +1! I had thought of CQS first... :)

Answer (score 0):

The participation of `Receiver` in this pattern is not really important, it is just to emphasize the fact that the concrete command object masked behind the very simple `Command` interface can do a significant thing and even that thing is actually handled by another object (`Receiver`) not the command object itself.

Indeed, the point of Command Pattern is to encapsulate a complicated task into a minimal interface (just a void method -- `void execute()` -- that does not require any parameter) so that one or many tasks can be easily stored and passed to anywhere for later invoking by an `Invoker`. This is very convenient for the `Invoker` since the `Command` interface is minimal.

A clear example of `Command` is the well-known `Runnable` interface in Java.

Comment: I was thinking that the Receiver could be setup to communicate with different systems.  For example, we need to create a new user account, but creating a new user involves communicating with two systems.  In that case, two commands would be created ... one to communicate with system1 and the second for system2.  Two Receivers would also be created, one for command1 and the other for command2.  Now, from the client, you call the two commands, and they would know how to contact the proper system and do the job.  Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: Yes, correct. By this way, if you want, after creating the two commands, you can postpone the executing, just keep or pass them to somewhere, that somewhere, at suitable time, will execute the commands and the new user is created.

Answer (score -1):

The simple example of Command Design Pattern in C#:

```
using System;

interface ICommand {
    void Execute();
}

class Rifle : ICommand
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Rifle is in action : Pif! Paf!");
    }
}

class Cannon : ICommand
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cannon is in action : Bum! Bam!");
    }
}

class Invoker
{
    private ICommand _command;
    public void SetCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        this._command = command;
    }

    public void Action()
    {
        _command.Execute();
    }
}

class Client
{
    static void Main()
    {

        ICommand command0 = new Rifle();
        ICommand command1 = new Cannon();

        ///////////////////////////////
        Invoker invoker = new Invoker();

        invoker.SetCommand(command0);
        invoker.Action();

        invoker.SetCommand(command1);
        invoker.Action();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
/*output :
Rifle is in action : Pif! Paf!
Cannon is in action : Bum! Bam!
*/
```

Comment: You're missing `Receiver`. [Command Pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern)